# Only one of the recipients receives email, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mime, smtplib

What am I doing wrong here? Only one e-mail address receives email and not the other one. So `my@email.com` receives it and `yours@email.com` does not receive it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import smtplib, ssl
import email.message
import email.utils
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import formatdate
from email import encoders
def sendfile(subject, body_text, f_name):

    """
    Sends e-mail with attachment.
    """

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = 'him@email.com'
    msg['To'] = 'my@email.com,yours@email.com'
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body_text))

    part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
    part.set_payload(open(f_name, "rb").read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename={}'.format(f_name))
    msg.attach(part)

    smtp_obj = smtplib.SMTP("localhost")
    smtp_obj.sendmail(msg['From'], [msg['To']], msg.as_string())
    smtp_obj.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending to multiple addresses, `msg['To']` should be a list of each address:

```
msg['To'] = ['my@email.com', 'yours@email.com']
```

And when you call `sendmail()`, since `msg['To']` is already a list, don't enclose it in square brackets.

Comment: When I pass a list it throws an exception.

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'`

Comment: Did you also remove the brackets from around `msg['To']` in the `sendmail()` call?

Comment: My sendfile() call does not have e-mail addresses. 

`sendfile("This is subject", "This is body.", OUTPUTFILE)`

Comment: Your posted code contains this line: `smtp_obj.sendmail(msg['From'], [msg['To']], msg.as_string())`.  Did you edit this line to remove the extra `[]`'s around `[msg['To']]`?

Comment: Yup this is how it looks now. `smtp_obj.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())`

Comment: And you're still getting `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128637/discussion-between-r0xette-and-john-gordon).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to send e-mail using the following code.

```
recipients = ['my@email.com','yours@email.com'
msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)

smtp_obj.sendmail(msg['From'], recipients, msg.as_string())
```